# How to retrieve array element one by one in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi am trying to read a directory for html files and put them in array and retrieve one by one.

i used following code

```
$filelist = glob($directory."/*.html"); 
    $val=natsort($filelist); // Sort the array
    foreach($filelist as $key => $value)
    {
    echo " $value  , ";
    }

        $next=0;
    $ns=$next+"1"; 
    $filelist1=$filelist[$ns];
    echo $filelist1;
```

am getting html files in a array but not able to retrieve one by one

please suggest

Thanks

Comment: This foreach loop does that exactly.

Comment: actually all element show at once, i need to get element one by one i.e when i call this php page passing element id of an array

Answer (score 0):

That's echoing each item, not returning an array. Maybe it would be more clear if you change

```
echo " $value  , ";
```

to

```
echo "ITEM $value ENDITEM , ";
```

Comment: You need more logic in your foreach statement. Right now it's just looping through each item and echoing it. You need to put code in there for what you want it to do with each item.

Comment: suppose there are 5 files in there in a directory called file1.html,file2.html,file3.html,file4,html,file5.html with a current code it's displaying all these files once at a time one by one but i need to take say file1.html and do something and proceed with next file

Comment: That's what a foreach statement is. Whatever you want to do with each file, put that logic in the foreach statement. You can identify the file by the variable $value.

Comment: Thats right. But suppose out of one 5 file, i wanna take first file by click once and when i click next i need next file, this is what i wanna do.

Comment: You need to define what you want to do. It sounds like you want to manipulate the file from the browser?

Comment: yes exactly, i need to show the content of a file in a browser and when click next i wanna show next file content

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
$directory = "./dir";
$filelist = glob($directory."/*.html");
sort($filelist);
foreach ($filelist as $filename) {
    echo "$filename, ";
}
```

Also you may use

```
echo implode(', ', $filelist);
```

Instead of foreach

Return result like this:

```
./dir/christmas_en.html, ./dir/christmas_fr.html, ./dir/etpl_winphone.html,
```